# Train neural network model on multiple datasets

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

What I have:

1. A neural network model
2. 10 identically structured datasets

What I want:

1. Train model on all the datasets separately
2. Save their models separately

I can train the datasets separately and save the single models one at a time. But I want to load my 10 datasets and create 10 models with them in a single run. The solution may be obvious but I am fairly new to this. How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the concepts of `concurrency and parallelism`, namely [`Multi-Threading`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-python-set-1/), or in some cases, [`Multi-Processing`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiprocessing-python-set-1/) to achieve this.
The easiest way to code will be by using [`concurrent-futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module of python.

> You can call the training function on model for each dataset to be used, all under the ThreadPoolExecutor, in order to fire parallel threads for performing individual trainings.

### Code can be somewhat like this:

###### Step 1: Necessary imports

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten
```

###### Step 2: Creating and building model

```
def create_model():                                                 # responsible for creating model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Flatten())                                            # adding NN layers
    model.add(Dense(64))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    # ........ so on
    model.compile(optimizer='..', loss='..', metrics=[...])         # compiling the model
    return model                                                    # finally returning the model
```

###### Step 3: Define fit function (performs model training)

```
def fit(model, XY_train):                                      # performs model.fit(...parameters...)
    model.fit(XY_train[0], XY_train[1], epochs=5, validation_split=0.3)     # use your already defined x_train, y_train
    return model                                                    # finally returns trained model
```

###### Step 4: Parallel trainer method, fires simultaneous training with TPE context manager

```
# trains provided model on each dataset parallelly by using multi-threading
def parallel_trainer(model, XY_train_datasets : list[tuple]):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = len(XY_train_datasets)) as executor:
        futureObjs = [
            executor.submit(
                lambda ds: fit(model, ds), XY_train_datasets) # Call Fit for each dataset iterate through the datasets
            ]

        for i, obj in enumerate(as_completed(futureObjs)):          # iterate through trained models
            (obj.result()).save(f"{i}.model")                       # save models
```

###### Step 5: Create model, load dataset, call parallel trainer

```
model = create_model()                                              # create the model

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist                                     # get dataset - for example :- mnist dataset
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()            # get (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)
datasets = [(x_train, y_train)]*10                                  # list of dataset paths (in your case, same dataset used 10 times)

parallel_trainer(model, datasets)                                   # call parallel trainer
```

#### Whole program

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten


def create_model():                                                 # responsible for creating model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Flatten())                                            # adding NN layers
    model.add(Dense(64))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    # ........ so on
    model.compile(optimizer='..', loss='..', metrics=[...])         # compiling the model
    return model                                                    # finally returning the model


def fit(model, XY_train):                                      # performs model.fit(...parameters...)
    model.fit(XY_train[0], XY_train[1], epochs=5, validation_split=0.3)     # use your already defined x_train, y_train
    return model                                                    # finally returns trained model


# trains provided model on each dataset parallelly by using multi-threading
def parallel_trainer(model, XY_train_datasets : list[tuple]):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = len(XY_train_datasets)) as executor:
        futureObjs = [
            executor.submit(
                lambda ds: fit(model, ds), XY_train_datasets) # Call Fit for each dataset iterate through the datasets
            ]

        for i, obj in enumerate(as_completed(futureObjs)):          # iterate through trained models
            (obj.result()).save(f"{i}.model")                       # save models



model = create_model()                                              # create the model

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist                                     # get dataset - for example :- mnist dataset
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()            # get (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)
datasets = [(x_train, y_train)]*10                                  # list of dataset paths (in your case, same dataset used 10 times)

parallel_trainer(model, datasets)                                   # call parallel trainer
```

Comment: I may not have made my self clear. My datasets are identical in structure(like same columns), but different data. So, different datasets. What will be the change in case of that?

Comment: that line, where you put (x_train, y_train) tuples for datasets :- `datasets = [(x_train, y_train)]*10`, here you can simply put tuples of different datasets, something like: `datasets = [(x_train_1, y_train_1), (x_train_2, y_train_2), (x_train_3, y_train_3)...]`.

Comment: When i took the datasets in this form ```datasets = [(td[0],vd[0]),(td[1],vd[1]),(td[2],vd[2]),(td[3],vd[3]),(td[4],vd[4])]``` an error was returned```TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given```. PS: those tuples hold the x_train, y_train data.

Comment: taking it in ```datasets = [(x_train_1, y_train_1), (x_train_2, y_train_2), (x_train_3, y_train_3)...]``` this form returns an error. saying ```TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given```. anything to be done to lambda when multiple tuples of datasets are used?

Comment: I've modified the code, just remove `*` in the line `lambda ds: load_fit(model, ds), *XY_train_datasets`.